# running tornado python in docker: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, docker, tornado

I have a tornado app with a file structure like this:

```
projectfolder
|_ Dockerfile
|_ src
 |_ __init__.py
 |_ __main__.py
 |_ config.py
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7
EXPOSE 8888

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "projectfolder/__main__.py"]
```

in `__main__.py` I do `from .config import Config`

and when doing docker run I get:

```
File "projectfolder/__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
  from .config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package
```

When I run the project inside .venv it works fine, but i cannot make it work on docker

Any ideas on how to properly import the files in the current folder? Or how should I re-structure my files in other it follows python best practices

Thanks!

Comment: If I move all files one folder up (together with the Dockerfile) and I remove the . The it works

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I guess you have a typo for `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "projectfolder/__main__.py"]`, it should be `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "src/__main__.py"]`, otherwise you will get:

> python3: can't open file 'projectfolder/**main**.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I guess you made some mistake when minimal your question, because `COPY . .` will not copy `projectfolder`, instead the contents of `projectfolder`.

**2.** Back to your issue:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.config'; '__main__' is not a package

Here, python find `__name__` is `__main__`, which means the script calling `from .config import Config` is a top level script, not in a package.

And `relative import` just could be used in package, not out of package. So you can just change `from .config import Config` to `from config import Config`, remove the `.` which means relative import then could fix your issue.